# Pandas dataframe wrong number of rows

Tags: python, json, csv, pandas

I've got a reasonably large json file of log data that I'm trying to convert into XLS or CSV.
Something in the process is taking only the first 1000 rows, and I can't figure out what could be causing this.

```
import json
import pprint
import pandas as pd
from pandas.io.json import json_normalize

f = open('GetLog.json', 'r')
writer = pd.ExcelWriter('output.xlsx')
payload = json.load(f)
df = json_normalize(payload, 'Result')
f.close()

pprint.pprint(df)
df.to_excel(writer,'Log Output')
writer.save()
writer.close()
```

The slightly sanitised json extract is below, but suffice to say I'm only interestd in the result, as the payload for messages is generally empty.

> {"Log":{"Messages":[]},"Result":[{"logdate":"/Date(1468270785461)/","message":"ErrorText","logtype":0,"module":"WatchFolder","logdateStr":"2016/07/12
>   06:59:45.461"},{"logdate":"/Date(1468270785430)/","message":"ErrorText","logtype":0,"module":"WatchFolder","logdateStr":"2016/07/12
>   06:59:45.430"},{"logdate":"/Date(1468270785398)/","message":"ErrorText","logtype":0,"module":"WatchFolder","logdateStr":"2016/07/12
>   06:59:45.398"},{"logdate":"/Date(1468270785367)/","message":"ErrorText","logtype":0,"module":"WatchFolder","logdateStr":"2016/07/12
>   06:59:45.367"},{"logdate":"/Date(1468270785336)/","message":"ErrorText","logtype":0,"module":"WatchFolder","logdateStr":"2016/07/12
>   06:59:45.336"},{"logdate":"/Date(1468270785227)/","message":"ErrorText","logtype":0,"module":"WatchFolder","logdateStr":"2016/07/12
>   06:59:45.227"},{"logdate":"/Date(1468270785196)/","message":"ErrorText","logtype":0,"module":"WatchFolder","logdateStr":"2016/07/12
>   06:59:45.196"},{"logdate":"/Date(1468270785164)/","message":"ErrorText","logtype":0,"module":"WatchFolder","logdateStr":"2016/07/12
>   06:59:45.164"}],"success":true,"TotalCount":5648}

Trying to natively import into pandas directly fails with the error: 'ValueError: Mixing dicts with non-Series may lead to ambiguous ordering.'

Ultimately, this is a script I just want to point at a webservice on a remote system and extract an hour's worth of logs once or twice a day

Answer (score 0):

Worked it out - ended up using ijson to load the json file and only the result values that I wanted.
Example code is here:

```
import csv
import ijson
import pprint
import pandas as pd

from pandas.io.json import json_normalize

#print flattenjson(x)
#pprint.pprint
f = open('GetLog.json', 'r')
writer = pd.ExcelWriter('output.xlsx')
df = pd.DataFrame()

for item in ijson.items(f, 'Result'):
    df1 = pd.DataFrame(item)
    if df.empty:
        df = df1
    else:
        df.append(df1, ignore_index=True)
f.close()

df.to_excel(writer,'Log Output')
writer.save()
writer.close()
```

Live version fetches the json from a server with a few parameters to specify date range.